# String concatenation in c#

Tags: c#, string-concatenation

One of my page uses jQuery in *.cs file as follows. But I heard that string concatenation will reduce the performance.  I can not write it in page (ie in *.aspx) because I am using UpdatePanel, which wipe out all client code.  Is there any other alternative method ? How about StringBuilder?

The code is in **MyTestPage.aspx.cs** and strings are concatenated using **+**

```
// Function to be called by jQuery
@"function ddlAssignCaseTo_SelectIndexChanged() {
    var value = $('#" + ddlAssignCaseTo.ClientID + @"').val();
    value == '1' ? $('#" + divAction.ClientID + @"').show() : $('#" + divAction.ClientID + @"').hide();
}

function ddlReviewedBy_SelectIndexChanged() {
     var value = $('#" + ddlReviewedBy.ClientID + @"').val();
     value == '0' 
         ? $('#" + divReviewee.ClientID + @"').hide() 
         : $('#" + divReviewee.ClientID + @"').show();
     value == '0' 
         ? $('#" + lblIn.ClientID + @"').hide() 
         : $('#" + lblIn.ClientID + @"').show();
 }"
```

Comment: have you measured you have a performance problem?

Comment: Have you measured the performance? I bet you won't notice a significant difference.

Comment: Is this a problem in the browser or in C# code?

Comment: out of curiosity, what is the @ symbol doing in this code? Other than that, it looks fine-- If you're trying to get rid of string concatenation on .js side, then I think you're out of luck for the most part. One thing you could do is have a code behind method which returns the jquery selector based on the client id, if nothing else, it will make your js easier to read and maintain.

Comment: @Adam Houldsworth - that is exactly what I was thinking.

Comment: Not making any sense to me, you are referencing ASP.NET elements in Javascript - where is the C# concatenation?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could do worse than use [`StringBuilder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) which is designed for this very reason.

Answer (score 2):

That's Javascript - are you building that up somehow in C#?

Anyway, if you aren't concatenating the string within a loop or something then the overhead of creating a `StringBuilder` is not worth it. A rule of thumb I've seen often cited is to change to a `StringBuilder` when you have more than 8x concats - but I've seen more benchmarks which suggest that it is more than this.

Remember that inline concatenations will be optimised out anyway:

```
string s = "string1" + "string2";
```

Is no slower than:

```
string s = "string1string2";
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case you should use `String.Format("#{0}", ddlAssignCaseTo.ClientID)` as this uses StringBuilder under the hood but allows you to keep your code concise.

You should certainly try and avoid concatenating strings for all the answers provided.